# How can I write this jQuery snippet more beautiful

Tags: jquery

```
$("#rightCol").children().children().children("div.entry").length
```

I tried this

```
$("#rightCol").children().eq(1).children("div.entry").length
```

or this

```
$("#rightCol").children(":eq(1)").children("div.entry").length
```

with no success. ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the layout (do you have DIVs with that class at other levels that you want to avoid?), you might get by with

```
$('#rightCol').find('div.entry').length
```

Comment: This is actually a more performant way to go compared to the universal selector("*"). $(..).children() is even faster than calling $("*").

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the [child-selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), like this:

```
$("#rightCol > * > * > div.entry").length
```

Though, if you know the child type, I'd use that over `*`.  If he level doesn't matter, just a [descendant selector ()](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) will work.

```
$("#rightCol div.entry").length
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
$("#rightCol *:eq(1) div.entry").length
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work, if you must have the specific level in the descendant tree.

```
$("#rightCol > * > * > div.entry")
```

However, this is more normal.  It would pick any "div.entry" inside of "#rightCol", regardless of the depth.

```
$("#rightCol div.entry")
```